# Flutter ListView+Bloc with Json Nested

Tags: flutter

Almost a day of figuring way how to do it and i need your help.

i curious what is the real issue since i think the code is correct. please need your help

i try to passing data from API JSON Nested to ListView.builder with Bloc schema.
the error said :

```
I/flutter ( 1770): Error Get Type & SLU List : 
I/flutter ( 1770): type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

here i copy my code

my JSON API

```
[
  {
    "ID_Type": "1",
    "Type": "Food",
    "Item": [
      {
        "SLU_Number": "3",
        "SLU_Name": "Warm Dishes"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ID_Type": "2",
    "Type": "Beverages",
    "Item": [
      {
        "SLU_Number": "1",
        "SLU_Name": "Non Alcoholic"
      },
      {
         "SLU_Number": "2",
         "SLU_Name": "Alchoholic"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Transactions_bloc.dart

```
class ModalType {
  final String ID_Type;
  final String Type;
  final ModalSLU modalslu;

  ModalType({this.ID_Type, this.Type, this.modalslu});

  factory ModalType.fromJson(Map <String, dynamic> json) {
    return new ModalType(
      ID_Type : json['ID_Type'],
      Type : json['Type'],
      modalslu : ModalSLU.fromJson(json['Item'])
    );
  }
}



class ModalSLU {
  final String SLU_Number;
  final String SLU_Name;

  ModalSLU({this.SLU_Number, this.SLU_Name});

  factory ModalSLU.fromJson(Map <String, dynamic> json){
    return new ModalSLU(
        SLU_Number : json['SLU_Number'],
        SLU_Name : json['SLU_Name'],
    );
  }
}

class typeandslubloc extends Bloc<bool, List<ModalType>>{

  @override
  // TODO: implement initialState
  List<ModalType> get initialState => [];

  @override
  Stream<List<ModalType>> mapEventToState(bool event) async* {
    // TODO: implement mapEventToState

    List<ModalType> typeandslulist =[];

    try {
      final response = await http.get(BaseUrl.ListType);
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);

      if (data.length != 0) {
        for (Map i in data ){
          typeandslulist.add((ModalType.fromJson(i)));
        }

        print("Print Type and SLU : "+data.toString());
        print("Get Type & SLU List : Success");
      } else {
        print('Get Type & SLU List Null');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error Get Type & SLU List : ");
      print(e);
    }

    yield typeandslulist;
  }
}
```

i created a call widget on Transactions.dart and i try call bloc on init state

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  BlocProvider.of<typeandslubloc>(context).add(true);
}

Widget asd(){
  return BlocBuilder<typeandslubloc,List<ModalType>>(
    builder: (context, typeandslulist) => ListView.builder(
       itemCount: typeandslulist.length,
       itemBuilder: (context, index) {

         final x = typeandslulist[index];

         return Container(
           child: Row(
             children: <Widget>[
               Text(x.ID_Type + "   " + x.Type),
               Text(x.modalslu.SLU_Number + "   "+x.modalslu.SLU_Name)
             ],
           ),
         );
       }
     )
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have problem when parsing your JSON response.

The `Item` should be stored in a `List<ModalSLU>` instead of standalone `ModalSLU` object.

```
class ModalType {
  final String ID_Type;
  final String Type;
  final List<ModalSLU> listOfodalslu;

  ModalType({this.ID_Type, this.Type, this.listOfModalslu});

  factory ModalType.fromJson(Map <String, dynamic> json) {
    return new ModalType(
      ID_Type : json['ID_Type'],
      Type : json['Type'],
      listOfModalslu : (json['Item'] as List<dynamic>).map((dynamic item) {
                         return ModalSLU.fromJson(item as Map<String, dynamic>);
                       }).toList();
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems to be a bad parsing of your response's JSON.

Try with this code:

```dart
Stream<List<ModalType>> mapEventToState(bool event) async* {
  List<ModalType> typeandslulist = [];
  try {
    final response = await http.get("url");
    final data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    if (data.isNotEmpty) {
      data.forEach((item) {
        typeandslulist.add(ModalType.fromJson(item));
      });
      print('Print Type and SLU : ${data.toString()}');
      print("Get Type & SLU List : Success");
    } else {
      print('Get Type & SLU List Null');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error Get Type & SLU List : $e");
  }
  yield typeandslulist;
}
```